# Fill down column according to colum in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've been a longtime viewer of this place and I love it!  I've never needed to post because I've been able to find everything.  However, today I am stumped and I cannot find an answer here so forgive me if this has been addressed.

The question is this:

I want to copy ColumnA (starting say, A2) from SHEET1 into ColumnB (starting B8) of SHEET2.

My problem is that the source column (SHEET1:ColumnA) has a dynamic number of rows every instance the workbook is used.  I also do not want to fill down to the end of the sheet or display zeros etc.

I perceive this as a filldown problem but sourcing from another sheet.  Though I may be wrong about that and cannot make it work myself.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Could you use the `UsedRange` property?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Public Sub a()

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 2)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sub copyToOtherSheet()
     dim startRowASht1 as int
     dim startRowSht2 as int
     dim loopr as Boolean
     dim counter as long
     loopr = True
     counter = 0
     startRowSht1 = 2
     startRowSht2 = 8

     Do While loopr = True
          Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Cstr(startRowSht2 + counter)).value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Cstr(startRowSht2+counter)).value
          if Cstr(worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Cstr(startrowsht2 + counter)).value) = "" then
               loopr = False 'you reached an empty cell and it stops copying 
          else
               counter = counter + 1
          end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to use a macro:

```
Sub copyRange()
  Dim rSource As Range

  Set rSource = Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
  Range(Sheet2.Cells(8, 2), Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.count,2)).Clear
  Range(Sheet2.Cells(8, 2), Sheet2.Cells(7 + rSource.Rows.Count, 2)).Value = rSource.Value
End Sub
```

This assumes that there is nothing below the contiguous range of values in column A on Sheet1, and that in Sheet2 you want to completely clear out whatever is in column B from row 8 down to the bottom. (If your range in column A of Sheet1 gets smaller from one invocation to the next, you don't want to leave any remnants in Sheet2)